# angular directive with ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I've made a very simple paragraph directive based on HTML `<p>` tag.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('paragraph', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.text = "Paragraph text from controller"
    },
    controllerAs: 'ParagraphViewModel',
    template: '<p ng-transclude>{{ParagraphViewModel.text}}</p>'
  }
});
```

I am using that directive in my html as follow:

```
<paragraph>This is a very simple paragraph</paragraph>
<paragraph></paragraph>
```

And I have an input which I've bound it to `ParagraphViewModel.text`.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ParagraphViewModel.text">
```

The problem is, when I change the input, the second `<paragraph>` changes as expected, But first ones value does not.

Please check [this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zudowep/edit?html,js,output) to see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're trying to achieve here is to pass your directive a default text and then change it with bound input.

You can achieve that by using Isolated Scopes. Here's how you should do it:

In your **View** :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <paragraph pgtext="Foo" pgmodel="bar"></paragraph>
  <paragraph>{{bar}}</paragraph>
  <input type="text" ng-model="bar">

</div>
```

In your **App**:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').directive('paragraph', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      pgmodel: '=',
      pgtext: '@'
    },
    template: '<p ng-transclude>{{pgmodel || pgtext}}</p>'
  }
});
```

**DEMO:** [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/feqeju/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Take another look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude), especially at this particular [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude#transclude-fallback-content).

You see, when Angular transcludes your content in

```
<paragraph>This is a very simple paragraph</paragraph>
```

it completely forgets about `{{ParagraphViewModel.text}}` binding in the directive's template because all the content of `<p ng-transclude>` will be replaced by the content from `<paragraph>` tag.

The second case is working as you expect it to simply because content replacement does not happen and Angular defaults to the content from your template.

Comment: so is there any solution for this?

Comment: Solution to what? :) It is supposed to behave this way. What is the behaviour you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dennis got the point. Angular will be replace your tag when using ng-transclude.